# keytool does not make for me alias password

Tags: release, phonegap, keytool

So I am following this instruction.

http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/signing/android/

Everything proceeded without any problem except for me,
the CMD does not ask me to write down a password for alias.

So no matter what or how I do,
I end up getting

"Error - Keystore alias not recognized: engdiaryalias - You can fix this here"

from phonegap build.

I've searched for like 2 hours and ended up here..
Thank you very much.

(1) update number 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6Hg5.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGsmR.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjLDr.jpg)

Click above links

Answer (score 0):

When you create the keystore file "-alias [alias_name]" did you use engdiaryalias?. Then verify your config.xml App ID is same as the alias.

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android-versionCode="1" version="0.0.1" id="engdiaryalias"  >
```

**id="engdiaryalias"** is your App ID

Comment: Thank you very much!! sadly, turned out this didn't work either... I think it's because my CMD doesn't even ask for alis password, but then again, when I do use phone gap build, it DOES ask for alias password that I didn't even make. pls refer to pictures belows.